# Datastage sequence job aborted because of ExecCommand stage

Tags: datastage, execcommand

**Datastage sequence job aborted because of ExecCommand stage**

As the picture shows, datastage sequence job aborted without any other error messages. The execCommand stage is to call a linux shell script. And I could run the script successfully by logging to the server as the user 'dsadm'.(By the way, I logged on datastage client as dsuser1, also having admin privileges)

[image: ExecCommand stage]

[image: runtime logs][image: stage properties]

Comment: Have you reset the sequence before run again ? This error message don't give information on problem. Is the $SHELL_PATH parameter passed correctly ?

Comment: Here , SHELL_PATH is an environment variable.You should be able find an entry for SHELL_PATH in logs(environment variable settings). If it is not set, please follow the procedure in the below link to set it. The environment variable can be set at job,project or instance level. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21648569